# JQuery onclick on select tag hide tool tip for options

Tags: jquery

i want to hide the tool tio of select tag when the drowndown is expanded .please let me know is there any way to do this

```js
function showselecttip(obj)
{_txt=$(obj).find("option:selected").text();
 
  if(_txt != ""){
  _txt = replaceToHTMLCodeForWritingOnJsp(_txt);
   Tip(_txt);
  }
  $(obj).mouseout(function() {
    UnTip();
   }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onmouseover="showselecttip(this)" >
<select ><option title="aaaaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option title="bbbbbbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
  <option title="cccccccccccc">cccccccccccc</option>
  <option title="dddddddddddddd">dddddddddddddd</option>
</select>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `title` of the `options` in you html. That would be the best way. Or remove the `title` attribute with js:

```js
$("select option").removeAttr("title");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option title="aaaaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option title="bbbbbbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
  <option title="cccccccccccc">cccccccccccc</option>
  <option title="dddddddddddddd">dddddddddddddd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: not like that can you give me a onclick event to hide it

Comment: Why would you want to do it on `click`? And `click` is not the beste idea here, because you can open and close `select` elements with the keyboard too. Than no `click` will be fired. @satwick

Comment: but in my project i want on click function to remove the tool tip when clicked on the select tag so i cant remove the "value" for over all project bro!

Comment: so plz let me over come this issue

Comment: Could you try to explain what you want to do overall? Maybe I can tell you a better solution for what you want to do. @satwick

Comment: i my project  the tool tip is  showing behind the dropdown, so i want to hide it or else change the z-index value ,, the above posted jquery is that i have used in my over all project

Comment: sp plz let me know how can i handle it show me the better solution

Comment: And can you tell me again, why you don't want to remove the title, or why do you need the title? @satwick

Comment: in my project i have title described default so that i cant remove it bro kindle show how can i handle the z index